# nth term of the series containing one 9 then two 9 and so on

Tags: palindrome

nth term of the series 9, 99, 999, 9999.

Is there any formula for it?

9

99

999

9999

.
.
.
.

Comment: 9...9 with n 9’s equals 10^n - 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general formula is
$$10^n-1$$
as each term is one less than a power of $10$.